# Definition clarification for $k$-colourable graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

If a graph is $k$-colourable, may we say that it is $k + z$-colourable for any arbitrary positive integer $z$?

Would a graph with $1$ vertex be considered $2$ colourable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest number of colors needed to color the vertices of a graph $G$ is called its *chromatic number*, $\chi(G) =k$.  And yes, such a graph is $k+z$-colorable, for $z \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Right, $G$ is $k+z$-colourable if $G$ can be coloured using $k+z$ **or fewer** colours. My answer was nonsense.

Comment: Well... the "or fewer" is covered by $z \in \mathbb{N}$.... which contains $z = 0$.

Comment: Exactly, I wasn't thinking.